# How to handle the browser's native auth dialog with protractor

Tags: node.js, authentication, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I need to test a webpage with protractor (nodeJs). This site is protected and the browser will show its native auth dialog when you try to enter it. We used to add the username and password to the url like this

```
https://username:password@example.com
```

but this approach didn't work in chrome or firefox (I don't remember which one it was).

If you fill in the dialog and submit, the browser makes the same request again adding the following header

```
header: { Authorization: "Basic bF0A23Zwdfsf==" }
```

Back to protractor, the first thing the script does is

```
browser.driver.get('https://example.com');
```

So my first question is: Is it possible to somehow add headers?

I've also tried to call `fetch` inside `onPrepare` (this is before the `browser.driver.get`)

```
browser.driver.executeScript(function () {
    let headers = new Headers({"Authorization": "Basic " + new Buffer("username" + ":" + "password").toString("base64")});
    let myInit = {method: "GET", headers: headers};
    fetch("https://example.com", headers);
});
```

For some reason `fetch` seems to ignore the `Authorization` header (it is not present in the request).

Anyway, this problem is getting complex, which is why I'm posting here. Does anyone know the solution or have suggestions?

Comment: Use a proxy server to inject your header: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Answer (score 1):

I get answer from [@Florent B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887618/florent-b). Thanks!!

Protractor doesn't have api for Basic Auth.

So I use [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to add Basic Auth Header to request by Protractor.

### How

#### 1. Install node-http-proxy

`$ npm install --save http-proxy`

#### 2. Edit protractor.conf.js

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy;
var PORT_PROXY_SERVER = 8899;
exports.config = {
  // do something
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'proxy': {
            proxyType: 'manual',
            httpProxy: `localhost:${PORT_PROXY_SERVER}`,
            sslProxy: `localhost:${PORT_PROXY_SERVER}`
        }
    },        
    onPrepare: function () {
        // create proxy server
        proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
        target: 'https://REAL_HOST.COM', // edit here
        auth: 'USER_NAME:PASSWORD',      // edit here
        changeOrigin: true
    }).listen(PORT_PROXY_SERVER);
  }
  // other your setting
};
```

Running above code, your protractor access to `http://localhost:8899`. ProxyServer pass it to `https://REAL_HOST.COM` with Basic Auth Header.